# How do I delete an item in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing a Ruby on Rails course and I am on a part where I am trying to delete a portfolio item but it is giving me an error. Here's the error.

---

`ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey in PortfoliosController#destroy`

---

`PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "portfolios" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_cc5ab4a1c3" on table "technologies" DETAIL: Key (id)=(12) is still referenced from table "technologies". : DELETE FROM "portfolios" WHERE "portfolios"."id" = $1`

---

`Extracted source (around line #52):`

---

```
50
51 # Destroy/delete the record
52 @portfolio_item.destroy
53
54 # Redirect
55 respond_to do |format|`
```

---

`Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/DevcampPortfolio/ClonedRepo/Devcamp-Portfolio`

---

`Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/portfolios_controller.rb:52:in 'destroy'`

---

`Request`

`Parameters:`

`{"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"3fGuZqFrTblpS7aQGpfszjN24lSxu6SAr5/JRlLc0RDupDZ7BJKJr6kPnEYHa0/BR7rmTPnN+/i5Ptjb3wCLtw==", "id"=>"12"}`

---

`Response`

`Headers:`

`None`

---

[the code for the place I am in the course](https://github.com/jordanhudgens/devcamp-portfolio/tree/6aa7643fa1e84e1366dc9f3459137ccc0220e35a)

[my code](https://github.com/griggril000/DevcampPortfolio/tree/controller)

---

What do I change to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add dependent: :destroy to your has_many relation on the portfolio model.

has_many :technologies, dependent: :destroy
This will make it so that when you destroy a portfolio it destroys the technologies that "belong" to the portfolio.

If you want to keep the technologies you need to change the relationship between them, or allow them to be parentless and hook a before_destroy action to the portfolio model.

Comment: I tried to do what you said but I couldn't figure it out. Could you show me what the code is with the dependent: :destroy part? I'm new at rails and I don't know much.

Comment: In your portfolio.rb file, write "has_many technologies, dependent: : destroy" it will kill elements in technologies table belonging to that very portfolio when you destroy it(I am answering your comment, not the thread btw)

Comment: Postgres doesn't like you kill a parent and leaves child referring to that parent. The foreign_key to portfolio, located in technologies, then points to nothing. I think with other databases than pg, you can delete parent without killing references to it.

Comment: That didn't work @Maxence. On the portfolios page, it now says `undefined method 'technologies' for #<Class:0x007f9a0db20f58>`

Comment: Sorry maybe a typo. Portfolio model should show " has_many :technologies, dependent: :destroy " I forgot colon before thechnologies

Comment: No pb. By the way not adding dependent destroy may work just fine with another database program than pg, that can be confusing: you follow tutorial but it may not work your side, depending on setup.